# Netflix HD on PC

Tags: windows-7, netflix

Some content on Netflix says ["Available in HD on your TV"](http://movies2.netflix.com/WiMovie/Arrested_Development/70140358?trkid=50000009). Whats does this meen? Only through an Xbox360/PS3?

I chatted with their support, who told me it would work if I connected my PC to a TV with an HDMI cable. Has anyone tried this? Can a Silverlight application really detect this?

Is there any way to play back this content on my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HD streams are available through Silverlight on your PC as long as you have the bandwidth to support it. Keep in mind that if your current connection is too slow (in it's calculations) to support an HD stream, it will play the SD Version.

When it says "HD on your TV" means that it is available in HD form to Set-Top boxes such as PS3/XB360/Roku/AppleTV. Again, As long as your internet connection is strong enough to support it.

If you are not getting HD streams on your PC, its probably because of bandwidth issues.

Me, I have an HTPC and thus guarantee that anything I want to watch will have the best stream available.

Comment: But do you get "HD on your TV" through your HTPC?

Comment: Not technically, I get the PC stream, since its just a windows machine using my TV as a monitor. I get everything that anyone else can through the website. Thus, "HD on your TV" has no bearing on me.

Comment: Okay, but that was my question: how to get the HD content marked as "HD on your TV", to play in HD on/through my Windows 7 PC. Sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Any content played through the website that has an HD stream will play on a PC if you have sufficient bandwidth.

NOT ALL HD STREAMS will play on set top boxes.

Comment: (Sorry for the really late response) Nice, that sounds great! I must ask though, do you have anything to back this up with? It doesn't really look like HD to me, and my bandwidth and computer should be more than able to handle it.